# How can I open another UIViewController when user taps on my container in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController and it contains a container with embedded another UIViewController. I want to display the third UIViewController when user taps on the container.

So far I managed to do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var requestDetails: UIView!  //my embedded container

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showRequest:")
    requestDetails.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
}

func showRequest(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("hi")    
}
```

Now when user taps the container I can print `hi` to the console. But instead I want to present on fullscreen another UIViewController called `fullscreenViewController`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self presentViewController:fullScreenViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or you could also add a gesture to your view in your storyboard, and add a segue to this gesture.

Comment: Can you give me a hint how could I do it from storyboard? I cannot find such option there :|

Comment: When you're in your storyboard, you can add a gesture just like if you were adding a viewcontroller. So, you put a tap gesture recognizer on the view you want to click on, and you ctrl+click the gesture (in the left menu) and drag it to the viewcontroller you want to open.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the swift version:

```
presentViewController(fullScreenViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And of course you can do that from the storyboard:

[image]

You just have to CTRL+Click on a button for example, and drag to the view controller you want to show, and click on `show`

Hope it helps you